# Is ClusterIP able to load balance traffic for multiple pods?

Tags: kubernetes

I created a `ReplicaSet` with `replicas = 3`. These pods `internal-pod-a`, `internal-pod-b`, `internal-pod-c` serve for internal needs only. Then I created a service with `ClusterIP` type to route requests to the pods.

For testing purposes I tried to see how the traffic will be distributed. After port forwarding, I executed several requests to the service:

```
kubectl port-forward svc/internal-service-cip 8081:80 -n prod
```

All the requests were served on the same pod `internal-pod-a`.

So I'm confused, why does the `ClusterIP` send all requests to the same pod?

k8s manifests:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  namespace: prod
  name: internal-pod
  labels:
    app: internal-pod
    environment: prod
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: internal-pod
      environment: prod
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: internal-pod
        environment: prod
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: internal-pod
        image: bla-bla-repo
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
-----------------------------
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: prod
  name: internal-service-cip
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: internal-pod
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
    protocol: TCP
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, a [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#virtual-ips-and-service-proxies) *does* provide load balancing across the selected pods.  You can see this using a debugging shell:

```
kubectl run --namespace=prod debug \
            --generator=run-pod/v1 \
            --image=busybox --rm --stdin --tty -- \
            /bin/sh
wget -O- http://internal-service-cip/
```

(The first command is the Kubernetes equivalent of `docker run --rm -it busybox sh`, but launches it in your Kubernetes namespace.)

Under the hood, [`kubectl port-forward`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#port-forward) always connects to some single pod (emphasis mine):

> Forward one or more local ports **to a pod**.  ...  If there are multiple pods matching the criteria, a pod will be selected automatically.

So if you `kubectl port-forward service/internal-service-cip`, internally it looks at the Endpoints of the Service, picks one of the matching pods, and port-forwards to that pod.  Since every connection goes to the same pod, it looks like there's no load balancing in this scenario.